# vim customized with emacs commands (insert mode only)

Tags: vim, emacs, keyboard-shortcuts, vi, key-mapping

I was an `emacs` user, and I have to switch to `vim`. But I miss some basic emacs commands in `vim` insert mode:

1. `C-A`
2. `C-E`
3. `C-K`
4. `C-Y`
5. `C-x C-s`
6. ... and some other

I know that I can press `Escape` and then press some of the following keys and finally press key `i`:

1. `^`
2. `$`
3. `d$`
4. `p`
5. `:w` *[Enter]*
6. ...

However I will like to stay in `vim` insert mode and avoid pressing `Escape`/`i` keys.

On the web, I have found customizations for `emacs` (`vi-mode`, `vip`, `viper`, `vimpulse`, `vim-mode`, `evil`). But not yet found the opposite: customize `vim` to use `emacs` commands...

I am interested about the `emacs` commands in `vim` **insert mode** only. Just some basic commands, as `bash` commands: `C-A`, `C-E`, `C-K`, `C-Y`, `C-U`... (yep `C-U` is not a default `emacs` command but I like it too).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*I am responding to this question four years later because the [answer provided](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/49206/17303) is a partial solution that does not completely address the original question.*

I have the exact same desire as olibre, and wanted to come up with a complete solution.  I come at it from a different perspective -- I'm used to Emacs line editing in bash -- but the issue is the same.  I want to carry that over into Vim insert mode (only).

The following addresses all of the keybinding requests in the original question posed by olibre, plus few extras:

```
" Mimic Emacs Line Editing in Insert Mode Only
inoremap <C-A> <Home>
inoremap <C-B> <Left>
inoremap <C-E> <End>
inoremap <C-F> <Right>
" â is <Alt-B>
inoremap â <C-Left>
" æ is <Alt-F>
inoremap æ <C-Right>
inoremap <C-K> <Esc>lDa
inoremap <C-U> <Esc>d0xi
inoremap <C-Y> <Esc>Pa
inoremap <C-X><C-S> <Esc>:w<CR>a
```

<s>The only bindings I cannot seem to get to work at this point are `<Alt-B>` and `<Alt-F>`, which would skip entire words.  Whenever I bind `<Esc>`, `<Alt>`, or `<Meta>` combinations, gVim (v7.4 on Windows) outputs accented characters.  Please feel free to edit this answer if you have a solution to this issue.</s> I have gotten Alt combinations to work based on [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15399297/366727)'s suggestion to just use the special characters. I have inserted them above.

### Edit

-- (edit is not by original answer poster) --

I used the following under Neovim and Windows 10. You might need to change the "A" into "M" on other OSs as "alt" might be "meta" elsewhere. I haven't played with it enough.

```
inoremap <A-x> <Esc>:
inoremap <A-f> <Esc>lwi
inoremap <A-b> <Esc>bi
inoremap <A-S-f> <Esc>lWi
inoremap <A-S-b> <Esc>Bi
```

Comment: Just a small suggestion: I think `<Esc>pa` would be better for `<C-Y>`

Comment: Looks like `<C-K>` doesn't work when the cursor at the leftmost -- it should delete the entire line but `Esc>lDa` will leave the first character undeleted.

Answer (score 7):

You can map any command in insert mode to anything using the `:imap` command, or save typing by using `:im`. For your first mapping, you could type (in normal mode):

`:im <C-A> <esc>^i`

Which goes to normal mode (with escape), presses `^` for you and goes back to insert mode. See the help for more info:

`:help :imap` or shorter: `:h :im`

Do note that you might be overwriting existing key mappings. Put the commands into your `.vimrc` configuration file if you want them to be there for every document.

Comment: thanks for you tips +1 :-) But do you know whether this kind of mapping has already been configures? (e.g. without existing key mappings overwrite). Where to find such project/configuration? I would prefer to re-use something already done (and robust), than trying to do it myself (and missing something important). Cheers

Comment: Should I ask/move my question to http://superuser.com/ ?

Comment: Thanks! You can see whether a command exists with the (logic) command `:im <c-a>`. If it says 'No mapping found', you won't be overwriting anyting. I don't think it'll get much more robust than that...

Comment: Humm... I have to code, test my configuration, then fix my bugs, and again.... But I do not know all the `vim` commands... Please, do you know where I can find a list of `:im` last arguments? FYI, I am also used with the following `bash` commands: `M-backspace`, `M-F`, `M-B`, `M-D`... It will be nice if someone has already done that and shares his work, isn't it? (something like `evil`) Therefore I could reuse his `:im` key mapping without doing it by myself (error prone). Do you see what I mean?

Comment: I might not understand exactly what you mean, but you can find all non-standard key mappings by typing `:im`. To make a higher-level comment: if you want to be able to use Vim on multiple platforms/computers without always having to load your own plugins, special modes or vimrc-file, I think the best thing to do is to learn/use the standard Vim-commands as much as possible. I made several key mappings myself, but always try to find the standard Vim-alternative. And it can be pretty quick. One thing I did is map `<esc>` to `;j`, making your nr 1 mapping as easy as `;jI` and nr 2 `;jA`.

Comment: Thank you @Joker for your advices :) But I cannot yet type on keyboard without looking at my fingers :-( And as I always write text thinking being in Edition mode (not look at the screen) => sometimes my text is interpreting as vim commands :-( Moreover my colleagues do not like working on Linux terminal because they are not used with vim and other bash commands. I would like to make their life nicer, and maybe they would appreciate Linux... The answer from @ire_and_curses fits more my needs but I have some conflicts between my environment and `vim -y` that I have to solve... Friendly

Answer (score 7):

Not a complete answer, but are you aware of Vim's so-called "[easy mode](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#-y)" (`vim -y`)? It is always in edit mode by defaut, and does quite a lot of what you want, and doesn't need you to install or customise anything. It does CTRL-A, C, V, X, Y etc. From the [key-listing](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#evim-keys):

```
Key mappings:
    <Down>      moves by screen lines rather than file lines
    <Up>        idem
    Q           does "gq", formatting, instead of Ex mode
    <BS>        in Visual mode: deletes the selection
    CTRL-X      in Visual mode: Cut to clipboard
    <S-Del>     idem
    CTRL-C      in Visual mode: Copy to clipboard
    <C-Insert>  idem
    CTRL-V      Pastes from the clipboard (in any mode)
    <S-Insert>  idem
    CTRL-Q      do what CTRL-V used to do
    CTRL-Z      undo
    CTRL-Y      redo
    <M-Space>   system menu
    CTRL-A      select all
    <C-Tab>     next window, CTRL-W w
    <C-F4>      close window, CTRL-W c
```

A much more powerful version of this is [Cream](http://cream.sourceforge.net/), which [remaps many more keys](http://cream.sourceforge.net/keyboardshortcuts.html), and makes the basic commands similar to other editors you may be familiar with.

There is also the plugin [Vimacs](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=300), which enables all the common emacs key mappings. It's easy to install, and may do what you want (I've never tried it).

Comment: Very interesting +1 :-) I an reading/testing all your links... I will give you more feedback later. Thank you. Cheers

Comment: Keys of the «easy mode» have nothing to do with Emacs ones.  But «vimacs» seems an interesting thing. I just installed, and despite being old it still works.